# Custom Linux log in prompt and system health check

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, login, prompt

I am looking for an existing tool or direction on creating a custom login terminal and system health-check scripts when booting/logging into my linux machine.

Upon opening or closing the laptop much like a "lock screen" I would like a simple terminal prompt as such:

> > sleeping... _

On Boot/Restart a simple prompt for a pass-phrase

> > login: _

and then run through the boot process section by section BIOS, MBR, GRUB, etc... and do some simple but colored "Red/Green" "Go/No Go" checks of the process.

1. Does this already exist?
2. Is this possible or probable?
3. Is this what a "custom" linux build would be?
4. Am I missing some requirements to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain a little more _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: WHY, I would like to do this is that I will be running fedora daily, TAILS occasionally and Kali from USB. Depending on what I am booting into. The configuration of the machine matter more and more. For anonymity, safe lab configuration and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Does this already exist?

No, because...

> \2. Is this possible or probable?

... computers do not work like this. You want to run something *before* the computer has booted, and then to modify the early boot process in some way.

> \3. Is this what a "custom" linux build would be?

No — you want to do things that happen before Linux is involved. You might be able to accomplish this with a custom *EFI boot manager*, like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) — but it's not really mean to do the specific things you want.

> \4. Am I missing some requirements to achieve this?

I think so. But then, I'm really not sure what you are actually wanting to accomplish with all this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mattdm, I do apologize if I am not able to articulate what I meant to. In the simplest terms, "can I scan my machine to make sure it is healthy and secure, before I even start to use, each and every time. And just throw a custom login prompt on top of that..." Thank you again, if it even makes sense.

Comment: The answer to that is "basically no". Linux itself will do something of a "health" check as it enumerates hardware. But for security — you have no real choice but to trust your hardware.